# CSS colors problem

Tags: html, css, xhtml

with a mixing of colors in different tags.
My source is:

```
<div id="page_header">

  <div id="header_logo">
    <a href=index.php>
      <img src="css/images/header.png" border="0" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="main_menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="http://mvc.local/blog">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://mvc.local/welcome">Welcome</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and on the bottom in footer menu:

```
<div id="page_footer">
  <p>&copy; 2011 Stefan Cvetkovic.</p>

  <div id="footer_menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

My css source:

```
#main_menu{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background: url(images/menubg.png) repeat-x;
}
#main_menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
#main_menu ul li, #footer_menu ul li{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    display:inline;
}
#main_menu ul li a:link,a:visited,a:active{
    text-decoration:  none;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
}
#main_menu ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration:  none;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000000;
}
#footer_menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
#footer_menu ul li{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    display:inline;
}
#footer_menu ul li a:link,a:visited,a:active{
    text-decoration:  none;
    color: #000000;

}
#footer_menu ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration:  none;
    color: #000000; 
}
```

Probem is becouse my footer menu rules is on main menu, no difference in colors.
Can anyone help, sry for bad english.

Comment: Can you try to explain what is happening, and what you want to be happening?

Comment: my footer menu rules editing my main menu rules

Comment: As your CSS clearly separates your header and footer using id's I don't see how they can be mixing. Anyways, take a look at this fiddle and explain what you would expect. I changed the colors to all be different so that it is easier to explain. http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/WjRqV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every CSS deceleration that has the styling that you need, append the path to the element you want to add the styling to:

```
#main_menu ul li a:link,a:visited,a:active, #main_menu ul li a:link{
    ...
}
#main_menu ul li a:hover, #footer_menu ul li a:hover{
    ...
}
```

Edit:
Just read your comment: the problem is that you append more styling, you should include the full path not just the element name:

```
#footer_menu ul li a:link,a:visited,a:active{}
#footer_menu ul li a:link,#footer_menu ul li a:visited,#footer_menu ul li a:active{}
```

Comment: I need difrent a:link,a:visited,a:active and a:hover for #main_menu and #footer_menu

Comment: You need to refer to only one when declaring it: #footer_menu a:link or #main_menu a:link - the same way written above.

Comment: Thanks i just do:
#main_menu ul li a:link, #main_menu ul li a:visited, #main_menu ul li a:active{...}
#main_menu ul li a:hover{...}

#footer_menu ul li a:link,#footer_menu a:visited,#footer_menu a:active{...}
#footer_menu ul li a:hover{...}